# Prepocessing textual data for Machine Learning

Tags: python, machine-learning, nlp

```
'''
    import pandas as pd 
    import re
    articles_data = pd.read_csv('C:/Users/amrit/Downloads/data.csv') 
    print(articles_data.apply(lambda x: sum(x.isnull()))) 
    articles_nonNull = articles_data.dropna(subset=['text']) 
    articles_nonNull.reset_index(inplace=True)


    def clean_text(text):



    #Make text lowercase, remove text in square brackets,remove \n,remove punctuation and 
    remove words containing numbers.

    
    text = str(text).lower()
    text = re.sub('<.*?>+', '', text)
    text = re.sub('[%s]' % re.escape(string.punctuation), '', text)
    text = re.sub('\n', '', text)
    text = re.sub('\w*\d\w*', '', text)
    return text

    articles_nonNull['text_clean’] = articles_nonNull['text']
                                     .apply(lambda x:clean_text(x))

'''
```

I am trying to use this code to preprocess my data and keep hitting the "invalid syntax error" on the last two lines from articles_nonNull['text_clean']. Could someone help with this and why this is happening?

P.S. I am new to NLP and this is the first time I am handling an exceptionally large unstructured dataset.

Answer (score 0):

You have an invalid character right before the "]" of the "['text_clean’]",
also use the backslash "\" to indicate that a statement is continued on the next line, this should work:

```
articles_nonNull['text_clean'] = articles_nonNull['text'] \
                                     .apply(lambda x:clean_text(x))
```